# DirectoryRef: use in 2 different folders

Tags: wix, wix3.5

In my installer project I have a harvested output of a referenced project which creates a fragment and, inside it, DirectoryRef element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="MyProject.Content">
            <Directory Id="dir9B0F2CD8423EA8141263E4CAA24D1234" Name="Data">
    <!-- subfolders, components etc. -->
```

Now, in my main wxs file I need to include MyProject.Content directory as a subfolder of two different directories.

I include `<Directory Id="MyProject.Content" />` as a child of one directory and it works fine, files are added.

But if I include it in another directory I get:

error LGHT0091: Duplicate symbol 'Directory:MyProject.Content' found.

How can I reuse DirectoryRef twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Id` of non-Ref elements must be unique. So, somewhere in your .wxs code you have `Directory Id='MyProject.Content'` twice.

Unfortunately, the design of `heat.exe` that is part of the WiX Toolset adds a lot of identifiers preventing your scenario. You'd need to remove the Id attributes and probably still have to harvest twice to get two different ComponentGroup identifiers. This scenario just isn't in the design of `heat.exe`.

Contrast that with something like the [WiX Expansion Pack advanced harvesting's](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/wep-documentation/harvesting/) solution where the `HarvestFolder` or `HarvestProject` element is placed directly in your .wxs code. Then you can place those elements in the appropriate directories and unique identifiers will be generated.

Comment: Any chance WiX 4 will allow to resolve it? It is now in RC state, I was thinking to give it a try.

Comment: Heat had not been improved in WiX v4. FireGiant advanced Harvesting will still work in v4.

Comment: > probably still have to harvest twice
This I tried. The pb is that heat assigns the same IDs to harvested elements, so they can't be used together.

Anyway, I found a workaround, basically by just adding several files explicitly. But pity it can't be done in a more elegant way without using more third party tools.

Comment: Yeah, we are trying to find ways to feed our kids while providing OSS tools. If there were more people funding development a lot more problems would be solved. As it is, development is slow. So focus is spent on customers who help keep the lights on instead of consumers who get everything for free